# Communication between Laravel API and different Nuxt Frontends

Tags: laravel, nuxtjs3, laravel-passport

I have a Laravel API and two Nuxt 3 websites: frontend and backend.

The Laravel API can log users with Laravel Passport (OAuth2, PKCE).

The frontend is using `@sidebase/nuxt-auth` to authenticate users with different providers like Google, Github, Twitch and my Laravel API.

The backend only uses my Laravel API as provider for the moment.

All this is working fine.

My question is now: Through which channel should I communicate between my Nuxt websites and my Laravel API to handle user requests securely?

[image]